# Selenium findElement(By by) equivalent in Python

Tags: java, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium (Python), how do we pass the `By` object to findElement()?

**Java** (this works)

```
By locater = By.id("username")
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(locater)
elem.SendKeys("tester")
```

**Python** (this fails)

```
locater = By.id("username")
elem = driver.find_element(locater)
elem.send_keys("tester")
```

Error i get in python is `'str' object is not callable`.
I looked this up in other SO conversations and its because python expects something like By.ID or By.XPATH etc.

I need a way to pass the By object and wondered it it is possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Python` `By.XPATH` is not a method of class `By()`, but string variable:

```
By.XPATH == "xpath"
```

Try to implement below code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

locator = (By.XPATH, oSignUp.listformfieldxpaths[0])
elem = oDriver.getdriver().find_element(*locator)
elem.send_keys("tester")
```

Note that `find_element()` should receive 2 arguments: `by` and `value`. Both are `strings`

Comment: Many Thanks @Andersson. Accepting this answer as closest to what i wanted. Would you mind describing why the `*` is prefixed to locater?

Comment: as type of `locator` is `tuple` you need to use `*locator` syntax to unpack values from tuple. To be clear: `find.element(locator) == find.element((By.XPATH, oSignUp.listformfieldxpaths[0]))`, `find.element(*locator) == find.element(By.XPATH, oSignUp.listformfieldxpaths[0])`

Comment: Thanks again @Andersson for the details & quick response. This has been very helpful indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work. Give it a shot

```
xpath = oSignUp.listformfieldxpaths[0]
elem = oDriver.getdriver().find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)
elem.send_keys("tester")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 web_element=driver.find_element(By.ID,'id_value')
```

or

```
web_element=driver.find_element('id','id_value')
```

find_element has two parameter first one is locator strategy and second one is locator value.

method signature

```
     def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None):
```