# Catching source with selenium before automatic redirect in python

Tags: python, selenium, redirect

Consider the following page: 
https://www.cvs.com/shop/advil-pain-reliever-fever-reducer-ibuprofen-tablets-200mg-prodid-1040240?skuid=420321

When selecting a different format, like 100 CT, a new price shows up. Copy that URL and navigate to it, notice that it redirects back to the original 10 CT page.

I want to get the price of what's on the 100 CT page.

Here is my code, which clicks the right format, but when I try to reobtain the url I still get the 10 CT page.

```
    format_header =  browser.find_element_by_css_selector("ul.--horizontalScroll.gbcvs-c-variantSelectorList")
    items = format_header.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')

    format_count = 1
    for item in items:
        text = item.text
        if(text == '100 CT'):
            break
        else: 
            format_count += 1

    browser.find_element_by_xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Count:'])[1]/following::label["+str(format_count)+"]").click()

    print(browser.current_url)

    browser.get(browser.current_url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that ran and found the price correctly.
You can get the price by using `print (driver.find_element_by_css_selector("p.shoppdp-c-productPricing__actual").text)`
[image]

Here is the method code for `wait_until_element_not_present`

```
def wait_until_element_not_present(locator_type,locator):
    if locator_type == 'xpath':
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until_not(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, locator)))
    elif locator_type == "css":
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until_not(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, locator)))
```

Comment: Which library contains "wait_until_element_not_present"? https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Instead of passing the locator type and the locator as strings, pass it as a triplet as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43347522/2386774). Now you don't have to parse the locator type and deal with each one differently. It turns your function into a one-liner which is easier to manage and more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

@supputuri's answer is the correct one, only I replaced wait_until_element_not_present by the following

> ```
>     WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
>     EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "gbcvs-c-addToCart__inner"))
>     )
> ```